# Bash argument with multiple values

Tags: linux, bash

My situation is the following:
I want the script to be able to be able to receive multiple value parameters.
For an example

```
./script.sh -u username -p password -h hostname -pk file1.zip file2.zip
```

The way it is made it can receive only one file as an argument e.g `./script -pk file1.zip`

I'm not sure how make it so $PACKAGE variable can receive multiple values. Not a pro on bash, so would appreciate some ideas :)

```
while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
    case $1 in
   -h | --host )       shift
                              HOST=$1 ;;
   -u | --username )   shift
                              USER=$1 ;;
    -p | --password )  shift
                              PASSWORD=$1 ;;
    -o | --out )       shift
                              OUT=$1  ;;
    -pk | --package )  shift
                              PACKAGE=$1 ;;
    -g | --group )     shift
                              GROUP=$1  ;;
    -n | --name )      shift
                              NAME=$1  ;;
    -h | --help )      help
    exit
                ;;
    list )             ACTION="list"
                ;;
    "install" )        ACTION="install"
                ;;
    "upload-install")  ACTION="upload-install"
                ;;
    upload )           ACTION="upload"
                ;;
    download )         ACTION="download"
                ;;
    delete )           ACTION="delete"
                ;;
    * )                usage   exit 1
    esac
    shift
done
```

Comment: Before you think about how you might *implement* it in bash or any other language, you have to design the specifics of the behavior.  How do you intend that the script or a human would recognize the end of the package list?  In particular, if other arguments follow the last package in the list, what indicates that they are not packages?

Comment: You should not view it as incidental that what you describe is contrary to convention for command-line arguments.  You can undoubtedly get something along these lines to work, but it will be unintuitive.  Conventionally, options take either zero arguments or one.

Comment: As for the `PACKAGE` variable itself, you want to use an array.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The end of the package list is a long as there are no more arguments to -pk seperated by spaces. I tried an array, but it didn't work. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: you seem to be designing the script with an assumption the last flag will be `-pk` and thus all entries following it will be packages/files; what if someone calls the script like such: `./script.sh -pk file1 file2 -u username -p password`? while ***you*** may not call it like that, this is a valid `bash` script call (eg, your `while/case` logic makes no assumptions about the order in which flags are provided)

Comment: from a design perspective there are a couple (typical) methods: `./script.sh -pk file1 -u username -p password -pk file2 -pk file3`; of if you will ***always*** require at least one package/file to process then drop the `-pk` flag and require that all package/file names come after all flags, eg: `./script.sh -u username -p password file1 file2 file3` (yeah, you'll need to add some logic to your `while/case` logic)